# How to reset or reinstall emacs custom themes after erasing or overwriting a theme

Tags: emacs, themes

I am new to Emacs, (using emacs25), and I went to custom themes. I believe I accidentally overwrote the details of a theme called Misterioso.

I want the default misterioso customization.

I have tried to

```
$ sudo apt-get purge emacs25
```

and

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove emacs25
```

then I reinstalled emacs25.

The custom theme misterioso is still destroyed, it reads:

`misterioso -- Created 2018-10-15.`

How do I actually reset to get this theme back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .emacs directory there should be a file `custom.el`, this will contain any customizations you have done through the `customize` mode. Removing this file will reset all customizations.

Comment: I went into `emacs.d/` and found `misterioso-theme.el` 

When I deleted that file, all went back to normal.

Thanks!